# Pulling latest values using distinct and max

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this if I 'select *'

```
+----+--------+------+------------+
| id | name   | task | day        |
+----+--------+------+------------+
|  1 | Rodney | 2    | 2016-05-05 |
|  2 | Rodney | 2    | 2016-05-08 |
|  3 | Rodney | 8    | 2016-05-08 |
|  4 | Scott  | 2    | 2016-05-05 |
|  5 | Scott  | 8    | 2016-05-05 |
|  6 | Frank  | 2    | 2016-05-05 |
|  7 | Frank  | 2    | 2016-05-08 |
+----+--------+------+------------+
```

What I'm trying to achive is a query that will get the last entered 'task' for each person. So, in this case I would want back:

```
 2 | Rodney | 2    | 2016-05-08 
 3 | Rodney | 8    | 2016-05-08
 4 | Scott  | 2    | 2016-05-05
 5 | Scott  | 8    | 2016-05-05
 7 | Frank  | 2    | 2016-05-08
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use distinct against name & task and max for the most recent entry. Just not sure how to structure the two of them together to get the result.

```
select distinct name, task from test;
```

Gets me close...

```
+--------+------+
| name   | task |
+--------+------+
| Rodney | 2    |
| Rodney | 8    |
| Scott  | 2    |
| Scott  | 8    |
| Frank  | 2    |
+--------+------+
```

But no date...My SQL is limited. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `GROUP BY` and `MAX(day)`? You'll need to consider which row should be returned if a user completes the same task more than once in the same day.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate your rows so as to get the latest day per name. Then access the table again to get the records matching thse days:

```
select *
from test
where (name, day) in
(
  select name, max(day)
  from test
  group by name
);
```

Another way is to select the records for which *not exists* a later record for the same name:

```
select *
from test
where not exists
(
  select *
  from test later
  where later.name = test.name
  and later.day > test.day
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return all the tasks for each person completed on the last day rather than the last task for each person?

Comment: @John Pasquet: Isn't this the desired result? The expected results shown include two records of 2016-05-08 for Rodney for example, which is exactly what my query returns.

Comment: That did it, Thorsten! Thanks.

Comment: @Vrildox So you wanted the last date for each task?  Or all the tasks completed on the last day?

Comment: @John Pasquet: No, the tasks entered on the last day per person.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ok.  I assumed the very last task.